# How to to call a python script to execute as part of an EC2 cluster workflow via aws cli?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I am calling for the creation of an ec2 instance like so:

```
aws2 emr create-cluster \
--name "Spark cluster with step" \
--release-label emr-5.24.1 \
--applications Name=Spark \
--log-uri s3://boris-log-bucket/logs/ \
--ec2-attributes KeyName=boris-aws,EmrManagedMasterSecurityGroup=sg-...,EmrManagedSlaveSecurityGroup=sg-... \
--instance-type m5.xlarge \
--instance-count 1 \
--bootstrap-actions Path=s3://boris-set-up/bootstrap_file2.sh \
--steps Type=Spark,Name="Spark job",ActionOnFailure=CONTINUE,Args=[--deploy-mode,cluster,--master,yarn] \
--use-default-roles \
--no-auto-terminate
```

The contents of `bootstrap_file2.sh` include:

```
aws s3 sync s3://boris-scripts/ /home/hadoop/
```

Which will copy a python script into the ec2 instance.

Now I want to have something along the lines of "Once bootstrap finishes, run the python script"

I've tried two things:
1) I added the line `sudo python3 my_script.py` into the bootstrap bash script and it fails
2) I modified the steps to be `--steps Type=Spark,Name="Spark job",ActionOnFailure=CONTINUE,Args=[--deploy-mode,cluster,--master,yarn,s3://boris-scripts/my_script.py]` and that also fails

My script `my_script.py` tries to grab data from Wikipedia and write it to /home/hadoop/ as a csv file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the "Command Runner" step EMR provides:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-fetchmany.html

Create a custom step with the JAR set to "commmand-runner.jar" and then the arguments to that command are the split-up (Unix separated arguments) tokens that form your command you want to execute (a `spark-submit` in your case):

```
--steps Name="Command Runner",Jar="command-runner.jar",Args=["spark-submit","--deploy-mode=cluster", "--master=yarn", "/home/hadoop/my_script.py"]
```

Comment: This worked for me after I removed `"--deloy-mode=cluster"` and `"--master=yarn"`. I'll take a look later why these were crashing the steps for me

Comment: followup question. How do I force `my_script.py` to be run with Python3? by default it seems to call Python2.7 as the interpreter

Comment: @borissh try adding a shebang to the top of your script such as `#!/usr/bin/env python3` but note that the alias for Python 3 may be different depending on the OS you're running on EMR (e.g. python3, python-3.4, python34, etc.)